# Why do recursive (/R) for loops have weird behavior in windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, recursion, cmd

It seems that the !DRIVE! should work considering Delayed Expansion is enabled. Why doesn't it? Why doesn't the code below work for first case?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "DRIVE=H:\"

REM DOESN'T WORK
FOR /R "!DRIVE!" %%S in (*) do (
    echo(%%S
)
pause

REM WORKS
FOR /R "%DRIVE%" %%S in (*) do (
    echo(%%S
)
pause

REM WORKS
FOR /R "H:\" %%S in (*) do (
    echo(%%S
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because... [**that's how it works**](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2033) (`for /f` options also have this issue). For has a separate parser and for definition is not affected by delayed expansion (try without `echo off` to see what is executed). You can use one of the two workarounds (with a subroutine)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "DRIVE="H:\""
call :rec !DRIVE!
exit /b 0


:rec
FOR /R "%~1" %%S in (*) do (
    echo(%%S
)
```

(with nested for)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "DRIVE=H:\"

set "cmd=for /R "%%DRIVE%%" %%a in (*) do @echo(%%a"

for /F "delims=" %%x in ('!cmd!') do echo %%x
```